# How to write a delegate protocol withe two same method

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates

I want to add some data into 2 different entities when certain button is pressed, I am using delegate,but I don't know how to do that.

```
@protocol AddContentViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)AddContentViewControllerDidCancel:(AddContentViewController *)controller;
- (void)AddContentViewController:(AddContentViewController *)controller didAddPlayer:(FailedBankInfo *)info;
- (void)AddContentViewController:(AddContentViewController *)controller didAddPlayer:(FailedBankDetails *)details;
@end
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why you would want to do that and why not just use an IBAction instead of a delegate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you declare a protocol , you have also to create a delegate for the same

```
id <AddContentViewControllerDelegate > delegateAddContent
```

and create its property ans synthesize in the .m file

```
@property (nonatomic) id delegateAddContent
```

in .m

```
@synthesize delegateAddContent
```

now you will have to send the data through protocol method that you have already defined through your .m file methods.

```
[self delegateAddContent]AddContentViewControllerDidCancel:(AddContentViewController *)controller];
```

there might be some class where you want to send the data.That class must conform to your protocol
e.g-->

```
@interface ClassName : SuperClass<AddContentViewControllerDelegate >
```

and then you will have to implement the methods of the protocol./
eg -->-

```
 (void)AddContentViewControllerDidCancel:(AddContentViewController *)controller
{
//the data will be received in the parameters of the method of the protocol implemented.here in controller
}
```

Also the class that conforms to protocol must take the protocol ownership

yourclassconformingprotocol.delegateController=self.

You can also define the required methods in protocol by @required and optional by @optional

See [Apple's documentation on protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two method names that are selected as different only by their parameter types.  As far as the compiler is concerned, the names of your second and third methods in the protocol are both `AddContentViewController:didAddPlayer:`.