# UITextfield didnt shown text when i click on tableview cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, xcode5

Hello friends please solve my problem

I have two xib , one xib has textfield and other has tableview that contain data from sqlite.

when i click on cell of tableview its store the data into string object and that string object used in .m file that contain textfield.

but textfield not shown text ..

i check all the things like text color ,background etc etc ...but still there are problem..

i assign simple text like

```
  nametextfield.text=@"hello";
```

But this above code is  also didn't work .

my real coding in my apps is here:

```
//tableviewcontroller.m

 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                         dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text=[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@
                     "name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                           valueForKey:@"salary"];
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   ViewController *vc=[[ViewController alloc]init];
   nameStr =[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
   salaryStr=[[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"salary"];
   NSLog(@"%@ %@",nameStr,salaryStr); //i got the value here
   [vc fillTextfield:nameStr:salaryStr];
   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

//viewcontroller.m

-(void)fillTextfield:(NSString*)nm:(NSString*)sal
{
    NSLog(@"string : %@ %@ ",nm,sal);// i also got the value here 
    name.text=nm;
    salary.text=sal;

   //but after this code textfield not shown the text ... :(
}
```

What should i do ??????

Comment: Show the code of **How you are defining the UITextfield** ?

Comment: Direct put the uitextfield in xib file

Comment: also made the referencing outlet and delegate

Comment: Then Show the Code of **CellforRowAtIndexPath**?

Comment: Add the delegate at **CellforRowAtIndexPath** for textField and disable the UitableViewCellSelection to none..

Comment: @kumar Ki see i add code ...

Comment: The best way to test a disappear UI is set the textField background to a redColor instead of white or clear, then find out if it is initiated, if the subview is added to the superview, if the frame of the ui is correct or if the ui is covered by other UI.

Comment: @user3007462 use NSNotification or AppDelegete object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@user3007462 you are doing in wrong way.

I assume your `Viewcontroller` (SomeAddress `0x456456dffg`)  is a RootViewController and `Tableviewcontroller` (SomeAddress `0x4563ghg5656`) is childViewController.

In this case why are you again intiliazing `Viewcontroller`?
If you again initiliaze you  `Viewcontroller` it will create new intance(some address `0x345345hfh54`). And you not showing new instance of  `Viewcontroller`. just moving to previous instace of `Viewcontroller`

So better use protocol concept to achieve this.

Comment: Please tell me 
how can i used ... because i am fresher

Comment: Check this **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers**

Comment: An also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578281/how-to-pass-data-back-from-detail-view-controller-to-uitableview

Comment: @user3007462 Above link should explained cleary how to ceate protocol and their delegate. Declare one protocol in Tableviewcontroller and declare  one delegate method. While moving to Tableviewcontroller assign that delegate method to Viewcontroller, and define delgate method in ViewController class. Before calling PopToRootViewController from TableViewController call delegate and pass data with in that delegate.

Answer (score 0):

Your need is to set a string to textfield in the previous view controller (here it is the rootviewcontroller) which is already created(initialised).

The problem is that your trying to create a new object of the viewcontroller(which is not the exact object of the rootviewcontroller) and set the textfield of that viewcontroller.

In your case there is need to set the textfield of an existing viewcontroller

one way of achieving this is passing data to previous view-controller using the **protocols**.

please refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343519/pass-data-back-to-previous-viewcontroller) for example.